# HTML indenting and readability

Tags: html

In all our projects we have a strict policy of indenting all HTML, XML, etc. to match nesting depth; but recently a question has arisen: Should `<head>` and `<body>` in HTML be indented to match nesting depth?

Essentially, it is a question of

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

vs.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I've seen both around the 'net, but which one should be considered to be the most proper?

Answer (score 3):

If the policy is to indent by nesting depth, the second one is correct.  However, I don't typically bother indenting them.  I'm sure I'm not alone, either.

Comment: +1 You're not alone. `head` and `body` belong in pretty much any html file. So indenting only emphasizes the obvious...

Answer (score 2):

**Second one**.
The first one has html, body and head at same level, which isn't true if you would make a tree structure from it imo.

Answer (score 2):

`<head>` and `<body>` are both child of `<html>` . so, the second one is more proper.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't indent `<head>` and `<body>` to save one level of indenting.

However having recently started to use two spaces to indent HTML (rather than four) I might change my approach.

As with any indenting, the purpose is to make the structure easier to follow and therefore *consistency is the only important rule*. If the style is consistent it is readable (with a little practice). Any other rules are subjective (at best).

Comment: +1 for not indenting, 2 spaces and consistency :)

Answer (score 1):

The most proper would be to indent both since they are both part of the HTML element.

Does it really matter? No. 
It might even be more readable not to indent them since the width of your code will be slightly less big.

Indentation is a personal preference. Do what you find useful for you to read it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no established standard. You should just stick to your company/team enforced policy or just whichever works best for you

Answer (score 0):

Indenting all elements would be the most consistent way, but maybe not the most useful.

Indenting the `html` element isn't very useful, actually. There is only one, and everything (except the doctype) is inside it. Not indenting it saves one level of indentation in the entire document.

Indenting the `head` and `body` elements is more useful, but the code is still resonably readable without it. The rest of the levels should normally be intended to the correct level to make the code readable. Try to be as accurate as possible, if you lose the balance in the indentation, it loses much of it's value.